# Need to extend my 802.11 G signal

Tags: wireless-networking, router, 802.11g, bridging, relay

I have a cable modem hooked to a D-Link DIR-628 that we use as a wireless router for a mix of Apple Macintosh and HP Windows 7 computers in our home.  The home is over 5000 square feet and the D-Link doesn't seem to have enough ooomph to get a strong signal to all the areas that are needed.

At my disposal to use and configure, I have an Airport Extreme Base Station, a Belkin F5D7230-4 wireless router, the D-Link DIR-628 Dual Band Wireless router and a lot of time on my hands but lack of knowledge on how to make all this play nicely together.

Is it possible to either bridge all of this together or use one of the routers as a relay to the other to sort of leap frog them all together?  If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the range of the access point in one direction only by building parabolic reflectors. The page below is a good intro to building them for wireless routers, but once you understand the theory, you can adapt it to you personal needs. Granted, this method does not cover your entire house; in fact, it limits your access in all directions. This would be a problem if you like to use laptops that you use in different places very often, but if you keep them relatively in the same place, it could let you stretch the network further in one direction. That's all I've got; I don't know how to bridge routers either.

EDIT: Forgot link

http://www.freeantennas.com/projects/template/